# Unable to get d3.js data.join and key function working when selecting line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is what I'm currently using.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Git commit history</title>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="f(data0)">Original</button>
<button onclick="f(data1)">Final</button>

    <div id="chart"></div>

<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>

<script>

var data1 = {"directed": true, "HEAD": "37e1d1e19f1ed57f8635ba4ba48d7a6a16ec52f6", "links": [{"source": 0, "target": 2}, {"source": 2, "target": 1}, {"source": 3, "target": 4}, {"source": 4, "target": 0}, {"source": 4, "target": 5}, {"source": 5, "target": 2}], "multigraph": false, "graph": [], "labels": ["master"], "master": "37e1d1e19f1ed57f8635ba4ba48d7a6a16ec52f6", "nodes": [{"message": "Add barn door", "id": "2b818acb7782772d0b43a0fbfd18320348c66d09", "pos": [182.04, 162.0]}, {"message": "Initial commit", "id": "5d49116ea5679a9eb21225f05dd4874b3a0b5e35", "pos": [371.04, 18.0]}, {"message": "Add animals", "id": "a21fd23c9a9742c93febff279d7f917d457c0f04", "pos": [371.04, 90.0]}, {"message": "Add chickens", "id": "37e1d1e19f1ed57f8635ba4ba48d7a6a16ec52f6", "pos": [371.04, 306.0]}, {"message": "Merge branch 'add-barn-doors'", "id": "f0f204010fe90e377f37c8e466110e49e420ac9e", "pos": [371.04, 234.0]}, {"message": "Remove cow", "id": "009d60bee58372a19e1188368ecfcc3c9ed5c2f1", "pos": [560.04, 162.0]}]}

var data0 = {"directed": true, "HEAD": "f0f204010fe90e377f37c8e466110e49e420ac9e", "links": [{"source": 0, "target": 4}, {"source": 1, "target": 0}, {"source": 1, "target": 2}, {"source": 2, "target": 4}, {"source": 4, "target": 3}], "multigraph": false, "graph": [], "labels": ["master"], "master": "f0f204010fe90e377f37c8e466110e49e420ac9e", "nodes": [{"message": "Add barn door", "id": "2b818acb7782772d0b43a0fbfd18320348c66d09", "pos": [182.04, 162.0]}, {"message": "Merge branch 'add-barn-doors'", "id": "f0f204010fe90e377f37c8e466110e49e420ac9e", "pos": [371.04, 234.0]}, {"message": "Remove cow", "id": "009d60bee58372a19e1188368ecfcc3c9ed5c2f1", "pos": [560.04, 162.0]}, {"message": "Initial commit", "id": "5d49116ea5679a9eb21225f05dd4874b3a0b5e35", "pos": [371.04, 18.0]}, {"message": "Add animals", "id": "a21fd23c9a9742c93febff279d7f917d457c0f04", "pos": [371.04, 90.0]}]}

var w = 1500,
    H = 50,
    fill = d3.scale.category20();

var h = H;

var vis = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg:svg");

var f = function(data) {

h = H*1.45*data.nodes.length;

    vis.attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w);

    h = H*1.45*data.nodes.length;

        vis.attr("height", h);

    var transitiontime = 150;

var PosX = function(d, i, location) { return data.nodes[d[location]].pos[0]; };
var PosY = function(d, i, location) { return h-data.nodes[d[location]].pos[1]; };

var reverseMap = {};

    for(var i=0; i<data.nodes.length; i++){
    var p = data.nodes[i];
    var hash = p.id;
    reverseMap[hash] = p;
    };

    function poslink(d, i){ try{ return data.nodes[d.source].id + "" + data.nodes[d.target].id;} catch(err) {console.log(err); } }


var linkUpdateSelection = vis.selectAll(".link")
    .data(data.links, poslink);

    linkUpdateSelection.exit().remove();

    linkUpdateSelection
    .enter().append("line")          // attach a line
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .attr("x1", function(d, i) {return PosX(d, i, "source");}) // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", function(d, i) {return PosY(d, i, "source");}) // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", function(d, i) {return PosX(d, i, "target");}) // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", function(d, i) {return PosY(d, i, "target");})    // y position of the second end of the line
     .style('opacity', 0);

     linkUpdateSelection
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
        .transition()
        .delay(function(d,i) {return i*transitiontime})
    .attr("x1", function(d, i) {return PosX(d, i, "source");}) // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", function(d, i) {return PosY(d, i, "source");}) // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", function(d, i) {return PosX(d, i, "target");}) // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", function(d, i) {return PosY(d, i, "target");})    // y position of the second end of the line
        .style('opacity', 1);

  var nodeUpdateSelection = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(data.nodes, function(d) {return d.id});

    nodeUpdateSelection.exit().remove();

    nodeUpdateSelection.enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.pos[0]; })
      .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return h-d.pos[1]; })
      .attr("r", 0)
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) {if (reverseMap[d.id]==reverseMap[data['HEAD']]){return '#99FF66';} else {return 'red';}} )
      .on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .ease('cubic-out')
          .duration('200')
          .attr("r", 15)
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
          .ease('cubic-out')
          .duration('200')
          .attr("r", 10)
      });

    nodeUpdateSelection.transition()
        .delay(function(d,i) {return i*transitiontime})
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.pos[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return h-d.pos[1]; })
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {if (reverseMap[d.id]==reverseMap[data['HEAD']]){return '#99FF66';} else {return 'red';}} )
        .attr("r", 10);

    var textUpdateSelection = vis.selectAll("text.message")
        .data(data.nodes, function(d) {return d.id});

    textUpdateSelection.exit().remove();

    textUpdateSelection
    .enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, 6) + " - " + d.message; })
                 .attr("x", function(d) { return 15+d.pos[0]; })
                 .attr("y", function(d) { return h-d.pos[1]+5; })
                 .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                 .attr("class", "message")
                 .attr("font-size", "15px")
                 .attr("fill", "blue")
                 .style('fill-opacity', 0);

    textUpdateSelection
      .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, 6) + " - " + d.message; })
                 .transition()
                 .delay(function(d,i) {return i*transitiontime})
                    .style('fill-opacity', 1)
                 .attr("x", function(d) { return 15+d.pos[0]; })
                 .attr("y", function(d) { return h-d.pos[1]+5; })
                 .attr("class", "message")
                 .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                 .attr("font-size", "15px")
                 .attr("fill", "blue");


    var labelUpdateSelection = vis.selectAll("text.labels")
        .data(data.labels);

var labelPosX = function(d) { return reverseMap[d].pos[0]; };
var labelPosY = function(d) { return reverseMap[d].pos[1]; };

    labelUpdateSelection.exit().remove();

    labelUpdateSelection.enter().append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d })
                    .style('fill-opacity', 0)
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return data[d][0]- 75; })
     .attr("y", function(d, i) { return h-data[d][1] + 5; })
     .attr("class", "labels")
     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
     .attr("font-size", "15px");

    labelUpdateSelection
      .text(function(d) { return d })
                 .transition()
                 .delay(function(d,i) {return i*transitiontime})
                    .style('fill-opacity', 1)
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return labelPosX(data[d]) - 50 ; })
     .attr("y", function(d, i) { return h-labelPosY(data[d]) - 25 + i*5; })
     .attr("class", "labels")
     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
     .attr("font-size", "15px");


    }

f(data0)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, during an update, the lines do not move as expected. I'll try posting a screencast of what is happening to explain better. My current implementation works for nodes in a graph, but not for the lines for some reason. I feel like I'm missing something silly here.

Full code over [here](https://github.com/kdheepak89/c3.py/blob/master/templates/index.html)

Edit :

Here is a [screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Wf4.gif) of what currently occurs. I want the lines between two nodes to stay between those two nodes.

Edit II :

I've added a full working example above, with the data included as part of the code

Comment: How do they move and what do you expect instead?

Comment: This [image](http://i.imgur.com/gmndI2F.gif) explains what I'm trying to say. The lines move to the new positions, but not as expected with the key in the function. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Dheepak not clear on _lines do not move as expected_ what do you expect...in the gif  lines seem to move in its correct place.

Comment: Is your concern about the slow link movement..on update?

Comment: @Dheepak Could you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I've added a example with data. You should be able to open it in a browser. 


My problem is that I expect the lines between two nodes node0 and node1 to **not** be removed and added again, but instead move along with node0 and node1 to its new position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your key function is referencing `data`, which changes between calls. The source and target nodes of a link are referred to by index, and the same index points to different nodes with different data. That is, for the original data, index 0 may refer to "foo", but with the new data the same index refers to "bar".

The easiest way to fix this is to save the index with the links in a way that doesn't change when the data is changed:

```
data.links.forEach(function(d) {
  d.id = data.nodes[d.source].id + "" + data.nodes[d.target].id;
});
```

Then your data matching becomes

```
var linkUpdateSelection = vis.selectAll("line.link")
  .data(data.links, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

and the update works as expected. Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0f1L2u8m/).

Comment: That is awesome! It worked. Impressive detective work Lars! I'm curious as to how you figured this out, I've only been using `console.log(...)` for debugging. Any tips for a beginner to javascript?

Comment: Well, in this case I really just noticed what you were doing in the key function and how that changes when the data changes. Experience I guess :)